# Unable to categorize bundle product in magento

Tags: magento, bundle

I am going to setup computer store in magento for that i have been used bundle product for customization of Desktop computer. Now i want to 3 category of bundle product in which 1 st contains Customization of "Desktop parts" 2nd contains customization of "software & services" and 3rd contains "accessories".

I have been tried to change in view.phtml with this code

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

But this code gets all the bundle product. and i want it into 3 categories.
I have also attached snapshot of what i want to develop. [image]

Please help me out in this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the respective template files for this and you can find those files under

```
 app\design\frontend\base\default\template\bundle\catalog\product
```

Note : override the respective template files above and layout file (Bundle.xml) inside your custom theme folder

Comment: Thanks for help. Can you let me know how could i insert separate tab for each of three categories same as currently it is a "Bundle" in product admin section.So, i can insert bundle data for each of the category from back end.